# How to create specific discord.js slash command for each server with my bot

Tags: node.js, server, discord, discord.js, bots

I mean how to enable or disable a discord slash command for a specific server.
Mee6 can do it with his plugins but if cannot find anywhere how to do that.
Thank you to listening to me
Sorry for my bad english by advance

I didnt see anything on the web talking to this so i have'nt trying anything yet.

Comment: An object-oriented approach would have you abstract your slash commands as objects (e.g. through the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)). This would enable you to only allow certain commands for certain servers, either through separate invokers or enabling/disabling the commands locally for an instance-per-server bot.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete commands for a specific guild using [Guild.commands.delete](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=delete).
Im not sure if this works for global commands tho

Example:

```js
guild.commands.delete("Command Id or Object Here")
```